# Dragging, resizing and rotating an image over larger image in OpenCV Python using mouse click

Tags: python, opencv

I am making a makeup app where I want to drag, resize and rotate sunglasses which are applied on the user's face. How can I do that in OpenCV Python ?

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: sir i am making a makeup app where i am applying sunglasses on eye ,necklace on neck, here i want to resize ,drag or rotate that sunglasses and necklace over user image with the help of mouse click in opencv python how can i do that

Comment: Welcome to SO ! This question really needs improvement. Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)